# Extracting a particular line from parsed_pdf [content] in python

Tags: python

Hi i am extracting text from a pdf using the tikka package but the i want to extract the 5th line from the extracted content , i tried with other pdf extracting modules but the kind of pdf i am working only tikka is able to parse it

Here is the code i have tried .

```
from tika import parser from tika import parser 
parsed_pdf = parser.from_file("mypdf.pdf")
print(parsed_pdf['content'])
```

from here i want to extract only the **5th lin**e and everything on the line after the word **seige social**

**Output of the pdf**

Bulletin des Annonces Légales Obligatoires – Annonce n° 2101700 du 24 mai 2021

24 mai 2021 BULLETIN DES ANNONCES LEGALES OBLIGATOIRES Bulletin n°62

2101700 Page 1

Avis de convocation / avis de réunion

PIERRE AVENIR 2

Société Civile de Placement Immobilier au capital de 99 271 260 €

Siège social : 167, quai de la Bataille de Stalingrad - 92 867 Issy-les-Moulineaux cedex
520 008 442 R.C.S. NANTERRE

AVIS DE CONVOCATION

Les associés de la SCPI PIERRE AVENIR 2 sont convoqués en assemblée générale ordinaire le mercredi 9 juin 2021, à 14
heures 30.

Desired output

PIERRE AVENIR 2

and

167, quai de la Bataille de Stalingrad - 92 867 Issy-les-Moulineaux cedex
520 008 442 R.C.S. NANTERRE

Answer (score 0):

```py
from tika import parser from tika import parser 
parsed_pdf = parser.from_file("mypdf.pdf")
data=parsed_pdf['content']
print(data[4])
print(data[6].split("SiÃ¨ge social : ")[1])
```

I guess splitting data by "\n\n" in order to get all lines and then accessing lines and words after "SiÃ¨ge social : " might solve your problem.

Comment: this is not working for me,  as it is giving blank spaces and for second part it is giving out of bound

Comment: Can't understand why this code is not working for you. I copied the text that you showed as `output of pdf` to a text file, and applied the same logic as I mentioned above, and got the expected output.